# Is it legal to define duplicated exception specification

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
void FooThrow()  throw(string, string)
{
}
```

I have compiled the above code in g++ 4.4.3 without any errors.
However, I am not sure whether or not this is a legal syntax based on the standard.

Comment: In the new C++11, there aren't even any exception specifications anymore, so this will be a moot point :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++03, 15.4.6:

> An *exception-specification* can include the same type more than once [...] even though doing so is redundant.

The standard always speaks of the *set* of types in an exception specification, surely that's deliberate.

I would be negligent to omit pointing out Herb Sutter's [article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm), which is best summarized as,

> # Don't use exception specifications.